# Java or PHP Code that will parse a string to get the value

Tags: java, php

How to write code that will parse strRawData to get the code, date, time, longtitude, latitude, speed, heading and ID. Store code value to strCode, date to datelog, time to timelog, longtitude to dblLongtitude, latitude to dblLatitude, speed to intSpeed, heading to intHeading and ID to dataID. Php or Java EE

for example

```
strRawData = A  261107  083015   1439.5935N 102057.0442E   6.68    152   ID=AMY123
           CODE  Date    Time     Latitude   Longtitude   Speed  Heading  Rover ID
               (ddmmyy)(hh:mm:ss)
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP came here for code not for help.

Comment: I'm just trying to know how can you parse a string without a delimiter/special char.

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree with RealSkeptic, you should come here after trying something.

Anyway, here you have a delimiter. It is space. The problem may  come if you have space inside your data but as soon as they respect the format you've given to us there is not problem.

Consider Splitting your strRawData on space then trim each string of the result to get rid of others spaces. Then you should be able to parse each String to the expected type